# How do I go about adding supporting edges to hold this shape without increasing density on sub-d model

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I have this spot with a steep gradient in a ship hull I'm modeling
[image: Initial topology of the area]

I want to add some supporting edges around this to hold shape since I am using sub-d for this model. This is my attempt at it but it creates noticeable pinching inside it and looks like a nightmare.
[image: My attempt at doing it]

Adding a simple supporting loop around it like this doesn't work properly either:
[image: Single support loop]
That causes pinching like this
[image: Pinching from support loop]

And I can only go so far with vertex creasing before the edges start folding in on themselves (and I want to learn how to do this without it).
[image: Edges folding with vertex crease]

I want to do this without adding too much extra detail to the base model but I am lost here. I also want to maintain the edge loop just under the top one while doing this. Is there a better way to approach this? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the .blend file with my model

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear this answer is too simple... So you want to avoid creases, but why dont you just add *one* supporting edge loop with the loop cut tool (i dont get the idea of your attempt tbh)? This should hold shape, keep added detail low and not pinch.

[image]

**Edit:** I'd had a look at your uploaded file, here are some more options.
I think the edge crease is the way to go, but if you absolutely want to avoid it, you can add two supporting triangles and if you want to avoid even these, try the quad version. Without crease, i think the supporting triangles are the cleanest, but you will lose the edge flow (which the quad version avoids). For reference i added the situation after applying the subdivision modifier.

[image]

Comment: I tried [this](https://i.imgur.com/mjQNBoC.png) and it still creates some pinching seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/PudWR4G.png) and [here](https://i.imgur.com/CcsY7Q7.png) since the hull is quite curved in both directions. My idea was to try to distance the outer edges but that just lead to inner pinching. Vertex creasing does [this](https://i.imgur.com/OBvutc7.png) before I get my desired shape and creates weird artifacts.

Comment: Maybe add these images to your question? Also only the side view is not that helpful. If you can, share the blend file.

Comment: @KuroNoz i updated my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use edge/vertex crease:

[image]

You can set up edge crease by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and vertex crease from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> menu

Crease less than 1, but more than 0:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question but is there any way to do it without edge creasing? It always seems to create weird artifacts when I solidify the model. But I would also like to learn what kind of topology would be used for this.